# Толковые книги по C# 4.0

Tags: c#, книги

Порекомендуйте, пожалуйста, хорошие книги по C# на русском. Особенно интересны издания, раскрывающие

- обобщения,
- расширения,
- замыкания,
- и встроенный язык запросов.

Я присматриваюсь к книге "C# 4.0 полное руководство" Шилдта, но сам ее в руках не держал и не уверен, что ее стоит взять.

Comment: Ответ тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0

Answer (score 3):

Мне очень понравилась в своё время книга Джефри Рихтера CLR via C#, но я её видел только для второго дотнета. Вроде бы она переиздавалась.

Answer (score 3):

Пока ничего лучше [C# 4.0 in a Nutshell: The Definitive Reference](http://www.amazon.com/C-4-0-Nutshell-Definitive-Reference/dp/0596800959) не видел. Но она на английском.

Answer (score 1):

Ориентируйся на авторов Макдональд, Троелсон, Шилдт, Либерти. Бери их любую по 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, все перечисленные вами фичи - это C# 3, а не 4. Но тем не менее, я бы рекоммендовал книгу [C# In Depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet/) Джона Скита. Это что касается языка — и да, есть альтернатива в форме CLR via C# Рихтера, но Скит намного лучше пишет (имхо).

Если нужен референс по BCL, то тут однозначно следует смотреть на [C# 4 in a Nutshell](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/).

Удачи!

Answer (score 1):

[Книги для изучения C#/.NET](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2014/04/best-books-on-cnet.html)

Там найдутся вещи на любой вкус;)

UPDATE: если есть уже хорошие знания по другим языкам/платформам, то я очень рекомендую книгу Барта де Смета [C# 4.0 Unleashed](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2011/04/c-4-unleashed.html) (есть версия и для C# 5.0).

В книге 1700 страниц, с удивительно высокой концентрацией мысли. Просто посмотри там отдельные главы по интересующим темам. Будет однозначно полезно!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй учебник по Шилдту.
Он очень интересный, много полезного, а главное - написан очень хорошо :) Сам на нем осваивался.

Answer (score 0):

Стоит почитать (правда на английском) [Accelerated C# 2010](http://www.amazon.com/Accelerated-C-2010-Trey-Nash/dp/1430225378)