# Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#

Tags: c#, книги, c#-faq

Вопросы о литературе по различным языкам программирования возникают очень часто. Здесь мы попробуем собрать лучшие ответы и рекомендации насчёт литературы и других учебных ресурсов по языку C#, платформе и популярным библиотекам.

Не забывайте, однако, что никакая теория не заменит опыта программирования! Читайте, пробуйте, тренируйтесь. Спрашивайте, если непонятно. Попробуйте запрограммировать свой проект, это лучший путь.

---

> Данный перечень входит в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683).

Comment: [Спецификацию забыл.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029)

Answer (score 213, accepted):

## Литература по языку C#

- [C# - Заметки для профессионалов](https://books.goalkicker.com/CSharpBook/) - Свободно-распространяемая электронная книга. Эта книга составлена на основе документации Stack Overflow, ее содержание написано прекрасными людьми из Stack Overflow.

**Книги для новичков: а о чём это вообще?**

- *Head First C#*, Jennifer Greene, Andrew Stellman (русский перевод: *Изучаем C#*, Д. Грин, Э. Стиллмен). Содержит упражнения. Рекомендуется многими как хорошая книга для новичков.
- *Pro C# 10 with .NET 6* (11th Edition), Andrew Troelsen, Phil Japikse (русский перевод предыдущего издания: *Язык программирования C# 9 и платформа .NET 5*, Эндрю Троелсен). Хорошая популярная книга, многие начинали с неё.
- *C# 4.0: полное руководство*, Герберт Шилдт. Несмотря на неоднозначное отношение к автору, книга пользуется популярностью.
- *C# 2010. Ускоренный курс для профессионалов*, Нэш Трей

**Книги среднего уровня: если hello world не проблема**

- *CLR via C#. Программирование на платформе Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 на языке C#*, Джеффри Рихтер. Неувядающая классика. Хотите знать, что и как происходит *на самом деле*? Это книжка для вас. Не самое живое изложение, местами скучновата, зато максимум подробностей из первых рук.
  *Предупреждение:* Русский перевод от «Питер» ужасен: вас ждут выброшенные абзацы, опечатки и ляпы, меняющие смысл текста на противоположный. По возможности, читайте английский оригинал.
- *C# 7.0 in a Nutshell: The Definitive Reference*, Joseph Albahari, Ben Albahari (русский перевод предыдущего издания: *C# 6.0. Справочник. Полное описание языка*, Джозеф Албахари, Бен Албахари). Отличная книга, затрагивает многие аспекты, расставляет по местам ваши знания о предмете. Сводит разрозненные отрывочные знания в общую понятную картину, объясняет, какими средствами нужно пользоваться, а для чего есть уже более хорошие подходы. Есть [online-глава о многопоточности](http://www.albahari.com/threading/), почитайте!

  - русский перевод главы о многопоточности: [часть 1](http://www.rsdn.org/article/dotnet/CSThreading1.xml), [часть 2](http://www.rsdn.org/article/dotnet/CSThreading2.xml), [часть 3](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2010/08/c-3.html), [часть 4](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2010/08/c-4.html), [часть 5.1](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2010/09/51.html), [часть 5.2](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2010/09/52.html)
  - Более новое издание в русском переводе (есть в pdf в Интернете): Джозеф Албахари. С# 9.0 Справочник. Полное описание языка. Диалектика: Москва • Санкт-Петербург, 2021.
- *Essential C# 6.0*, Mark Michaelis в сооавторстве с Эриком Липпертом. Хорошая книга для программистов, желающих овладеть C#. Знания других языков, перед чтением, приветствуются. От Эрика Липперта в книге представлены продвинутые советы, которые встречаются на протяжении всей книги.
- *Effective C#* и *More Effective C#*, Bill Wagner. О том, как надо и как не надо программировать на C#. Разбираются отдельные аспекты программирования, способствует углублению понимания языка.
- *Programming C# 5.0: Building Windows 8, Web, and Desktop Applications for the .NET 4.5 Framework*, Ian Griffiths (русский перевод : *Программирование на C# 5.0*, Иэн Гриффитс). Очень детальная, подробная книга, в которой найдутся ответы на продвинутые вопросы.

**Книги для специалистов: внутренние механизмы и пыльные углы**

- *C# in Depth*, Jon Skeet, Third Edition (русский перевод: *C# для профессионалов. Тонкости программирования*, Джон Скит, Третье издание). Имя автора [говорит само за себя](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts). Джон один из лучших людей, которые умеют доходчиво объяснять сложные вещи.
- *C# 5 Unleashed*, Барт де Смет. Фундаментальная книга.
- *Debugging Microsoft .NET 2.0 Applications*,  John Robbins (русский перевод: *Отладка приложений для Microsoft .NET*, Джон Роббинс). Основы промышленной отладки: WinDbg/SOS, дампы памяти и решение проблем в приложениях (почти) без Visual Studio.
- *Under the Hood of .NET Memory Management*, Chris Farrell, Nick Harrison. Полное описание всех тонкостей управления памятью в платформе .NET. Книга доступна [бесплатно](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/wp-content/uploads/RedGateBooks/ChrisFarrell/Under_the_Hood_of_NET_Management.pdf) на английском.
- *Expert .NET 2.0 IL Assembler*, Serge Lidin.
  В книге представлена информация о почти всех тонкостях низкоуровневого программирования на .NET, а именно на языке IL. В книге описаны детали .NET Framework 2.0, по этому на данный момент какие-то аспекты могут быть неактуальны.
- *Оптимизация приложений на платформе .NET с использованием языка C#*, Саша Голдштейн, Дима Зурбалев, Идо Флатов (Переводчик: Александр Киселев). В книге рассматривается моменты .NET с точки зрения производительности. Рассказывается об способах замеров и шаблонах оптимизации. Также там рассматриваются вопросы, связанные с GC и небезопасным кодом. (Саша Голдштейн — признанный эксперт в этой области.)

---

## Документация Microsoft и другие ресурсы

- [Документация .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/)
- [Документация C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/)
- [Официальная спецификация C# 5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) и [текущий черновик официальной спецификации C# 6](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/README.md)
- [Framework Design Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Руководства и соглашения по проектированию многократно используемого кода. Является выдержкой из одноимённой книги, Krzysztof Cwalina, Brad Abrams. Книга переведена на русский под названием *Инфраструктура программных проектов*, Кржиштоф Цвалина, Брэд Абрамс.

---

## C# и .NET онлайн

- [Проверить код 1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)
- [Проверить код 2](https://sharplab.io/)

---

## Литература по асинхронному программированию и многопоточности

- *Concurrent Programming on Windows*, Joe Duffy. Профессиональное использование многопоточности в инфраструктуре .NET от одного из лучших мировых специалистов по многопоточности. В книги описаны тонкости использования как stream'oв так и thread'ов. Раскрыто, как и когда использовать Concurrent-, Parallel- и Asynchronous-модели. Примеры в книге присутствуют от достаточно низкоуровневых (с использованием системных потоков через WinAPI) до высокоуровневых Task'ов и PLINQ. Книга написана под .NET Framework 4.0, поэтому работа с ключевыми словами `async`/`await` в книгу не вошла.
- *Concurrency in C# Cookbook*, Stephen Cleary. (Русского перевода пока нет.) Очень толковое разъяснение современных паттернов использования многопоточности, особое внимание уделено использованию конструкции `async`/`await`. Обсуждается решение типичных проблем, решаемых асинхронным кодом. Отдельно описывается работа с Reactive Extensions и TPL Dataflow.
- *Конкурентность и параллелизм на платформе .NET. Паттерны эффективного проектирования.* Террелл Рикардо.
  Книга содержит примеры на языках C# и F#, описывает паттерны проектирования конкурентных и параллельных программ как в теории, так и на практике.

---

## Литература по WPF

- *Pro WPF 4.5 in C#: Windows Presentation Foundation in .NET 4.5*,  Matthew MacDonald (русский перевод: *WPF: Windows Presentation Foundation в .NET 4.5 с примерами на C# 5.0 для профессионалов*, Мэтью Макдональд). Разбор XAML'а, лаконичные, но полезные примеры. Пристальное, но не навязчивое внимание к деталям.
- *Windows Presentation Foundation Unleashed*, Adam Nathan. Наверное, лучшая книга для новичка.
- *Applications = Code + Markup: A Guide to the Microsoft Windows Presentation Foundation*, Чарльз Петцольд. Фундаментальная книга великолепного специалиста. Написана довольно тяжело, много листингов, плотный поток информации

---

## Литература по ASP.NET

- *ASP.NET CORE in action*, Andrew Lock (русский перевод: *ASP.NET CORE в действии*, Эндрю Лок). Исчерпывающее руководство по созданию веб-приложений с помощью ASP.NET Core 5.0. Переходите от базовых концепций HTTP к расширенной настройке фреймворка. Иллюстрации и код с аннотациями делают процесс обучения наглядным и легким. Освойте вопросы, касающиеся входа в приложение, внедрения зависимостей, безопасности и узнайте о новейших функциях ASP.NET Core, включая Razor Pages и новую парадигму хостинга.
- *Pro ASP.NET MVC 5*, Adam Freeman (русский перевод: *ASP.NET MVC 5 с примерами на C# 5.0 для профессионалов*, Адам Фримен). Поэтапное написание веб-приложения с рассмотрением большинства важных аспектов разработки приложения: паттерн MVC, юнит-тестирование, инверсия зависимостей и т. п.
- *Pro ASP.NET 4.5 in C#*, Adam Freeman (русский перевод: *ASP.NET 4.5 с примерами на C# 5.0 для профессионалов*, Адам Фримен).
- *Professional ASP.NET MVC 5*, Jon Galloway, Phil Haack, Brad Wilson, K. Scott Allen
- *Programming ASP.NET MVC 4: Developing Real-World Web Applications with ASP.NET MVC*, Jess Chadwick, Todd Snyder, Hrusikesh Panda (русский перевод: *ASP.NET MVC 4. Разработка реальных веб-приложений с помощью ASP.NET MVC*, Джесс Чедвик, Хришикеш Панда, Тодд Снайдер).
- *ASP.NET MVC Framework*, Гайдар Магдануров, Владимир Юнев
- *Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework*, Steven Sanderson (русский перевод: *ASP.NET MVC Framework с примерами на C# для профессионалов*, Стивен Сандерсон)

Дополнительные ресурсы:

- [Get Started with ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/get-started) от Microsoft
- Видеокурсы на intuit.ru: [Разработка веб-приложений на ASP.NET](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/513/369/info), [Разработка веб-приложений с использованием ASP.NET MVC Framework](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/527/383/info).
- Документация по [ASP.NET Core](http://dotnet.today/ru/aspnet5-vnext/) и [ASP.NET Core MVC](http://dotnet.today/ru/aspnet5-mvc6/)

---

## Литература по LINQ

- *Pro LINQ: Language Integrated Query in C# 2010*, Joseph Rattz, Adam Freeman (русский перевод: *LINQ. Язык интегрированных запросов в C# 2010 для профессионалов*, Адам Фримен, Джозеф С. Раттц). Учебно-справочное пособие, в котором понятно и подробно описаны возможности языка LINQ. Хороша для старта.
- *LINQ Pocket Reference*, Joseph Albahari, Ben Albahari (русский перевод: *LINQ. Карманный справочник*, Джозеф Албахари, Бен Албахари). Хороший справочник по всему, что относится к LINQ. Рассмотрены новые конструкции C# для поддержки LINQ. Много примеров.
- *C# in Depth*, Jon Skeet (русский перевод: *C#. Программирование для профессионалов*, Джон Скит). Немалая часть книги посвящена тому, как работает LINQ.

---

## Литература по принципам, шаблонам и методикам разработки

- Роберт Мартин "Чистый код. Создание, анализ и рефакторинг"
- *Внедрение зависимостей в .NET*, Марк Симан. Несложно написанная книга про управление зависимостями в приложениях.
- *Принципы, паттерны и методики гибкой разработки на языке C#*, Роберт С. Мартин, Мика Мартин

---

## Литература по Windows Workflow Foundation

- *Essential Windows Workflow Foundation*, Dharma Shukla, Bob Schmidt (русский перевод: *Основы Windows Workflow Foundation*, Дхарма Шукла, Боб Шмидт). Для тех, кого заинтересовала 26 глава («Введение в Windows Workflow Foundation») из книги Эндрю Троелсена *Язык программирования C# 5.0 и платформа .NET 4.5*.
- *Pro WF 4.5*, Bayer White (русской версии нет). Более углубленный взгляд на WF.

---

## Литература по XML

- *XML.NET*, Джо Грей, Динар Дальви, Бипин Джоши, Фредрик Нормен, Фрэнсис Нортон, Энди Ольсен, Дж. Майкл Палермо IV, Даршан Сингх, Джон Слэйтер, Кевин Уильямс (Переводчик: И. Штерев). В книги содержится всё про применение XML в  .NET за исключением LINQ. Старовата уже, но зато там есть объяснение, как  внедрить свои функции на C# в XSLT.

---

## Литература по ADO.NET

- *Основы ADO.NET*, Боб Бошемин (Переводчики: О.А. Лещинский, А.В. Журавлев, Н.Н. Селина)

---

## Литература по .NET Remoting / WCF

- *Microsoft .NET Remoting*, Скотт Маклин, Джеймс Нафтел, Ким Уильямс
- *Создание служб WCF*, Джувел Леве (Переводчики: Е. Матвеев, А. Пасечник)
- *Основы windows communication foundation*, Стив Резник, Ричард Крейн, Крис Боуэн

---

## Литература по безопасности

- *Криптография и безопасность в технологии .NET*, Питер Торстейнсон, Гнана Ганеш (Переводчик: В. Хорев). Книга дает представление .NET разработчику о реализации и применении криптографии, цифровой подписи, аутентификации, авторизации и доступа к коду (CAS). В ней описывается, что такое симметричное и асимметричное шифрование, что представляют собой цифровые подписи и как их использовать в .NET приложениях.
- *Microsoft ASP.NET. Обеспечение безопасности*, Доминик Байер. Не смотря на то, что в названии указано ASP.NET в книге рассматриваются технологии безопасности под Windows, применимые из .NET для всех типов приложений. Это аутентификация, авторизация, олицетворение и Membership.

---

## Книги и учебные материалы по Entity Framework

К сожалению, до сих пор нет книг на русском языке, поэтому на русском языке можно порекомендовать только следующие материалы:

- [Руководство по Entity Framework](http://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/)
- [Руководство по Entity Framework Core](http://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/)
- [Работа с Entity Framework 6](https://professorweb.ru/my/entity-framework/6/level1/)
- [Центр документации по Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/)

Comment: Хм. Я бы поставил Рихтера в книги среднего уровня, Скита с Альбахари двинул в книги для специалистов, а для де Смета выделил отдельную категорию. Ну или первых трех в один раздел. Но уж никак Скит с Албахари не книги среднего уровня, на мой взгляд. Скит куда хардкорнее Рихтера будет.

Comment: @andreycha Это общий вопрос, вы легко можете вносить ваши улучшения.

Comment: Плюс за Скита, он красавчик!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я не претендую на истину, да и написавший этот список может не согласиться со мной.

Comment: @andreycha: Список общий, так что улучшайте!

Comment: Еще фидлы можно писать как для js https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: Книги по Silverlight, XNA и виндофону будут? =)

Comment: @Mints97: Если кто-то из сообщества добавит, то конечно будут. Это ведь не «авторский» ответ, а ответ формата wiki. Был бы рад, если вы добавите что-нибудь.

Comment: @MaLS: Спасибо!

Comment: Я бы добавил еще эту книгу:

_Паттерны проектирования,_ Эрик Фримен, Элизабет Фримен.

Очень интересный подход =)

Comment: @SoulMicro: А она по C# или по общим паттернам проектирования? Если по общим, у нас для этого есть отдельный список.

Comment: @VladD: Она скорее по общим паттернам. А можно получить ссылку на общий список литературы?

Comment: @SoulMicro: Вот: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474415/10105. А вот общая таблица: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454684/10105

Comment: Почти все из вышеперечисленного есть у меня, что приятно, конечно :) Могу добавить также - неплохая книга по проектированию: "Паттерны проектирования на платформе .NET" Сергея Теплякова.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Добавил книгу по архитектуре приложений от майкрософт. Очень подробный справочник, с множеством отсылок к статьям и книгам, многие из которых знаковые и известные.

Comment: @rotabor при внесении правки, оставляйте осмысленные комментарии, что вы изменили/добавили

Comment: Ок. Добавил "Джозеф Албахари. С# 9.0 Справочник..." Я знаю, где нужно было написать

Comment: Вопрос, Head first для начала можно заменить на сразу Тролсена? Уж очень head first мозолит глаза своими вывесками и картинками, или заменить её на что нибудь другое

Comment: @gachi_muchenik: А Шилдта тогда тоже выкинуть?

Comment: Шилдта перестал читать, все в один голос говорили его не читать. Да что уж тянуть, сразу на литературу профессионала переключиться

Comment: @rotabor А вы уверены, что новую книгу стоит добавлять в _самое начало_ списка, даже не внутрь никакого из разделов?

Comment: @VladD Я уверен, но у других участников может быть другое мнение. Если кто-то решит переместить в другое место - я возражать не буду. Своё решение я могу аргументировать тем, что эта книга сделана сообществом StackOverflow (как в ней написано), и она излагает материал, начиная с "Hello, World!", и до самых сложных аспектов.

Comment: @rotabor Я понимаю ваш аргумент, но настолько ли она превосходит все остальные книги, чтобы быть _отдельной_, _первой_ и _вне категорий_?

Comment: @VladD В какую категорию вы предлагаете её поместить?

Comment: @rotabor Я не читал книгу и не могу судить о её сложности и подробности. По первому впечатлению, там довольно много деталей базового уровня (например, раздел 47.1: как вызвать функцию и записать возвращаемое значение в переменную), так что мне кажется, лучше подойдёт начальный или средний уровень. Но пускай выскажутся и другие.